# solving Boundary-value problem ODE in matlab numerically

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

I am using matlab to solve the following ODE

$$0.02K^2 F''(K)-3.45 F'(K)-3.45=0.08 F(K) $$

subject to boundary conditions

$$F(K=0)=63.09$$ and $$ F(K=700)=0.$$

I found that I had to give `bvpinit` an offset such as 
`bvpinit(linspace(1e-3,700,10000),[1 0.1])`
from the left boundary `0` because otherwise, I would get an error

`Error using ==> bvp4c
Unable to solve the collocation equations -- a singular Jacobian encountered`

But this isn't really elegant, because the offset seems arbitary. This also did not extend the solution all the way to the left end point `0`. Would appreciate if someone can provide a better solution to this problem. Many thanks.

Comment: QIang Li, I have a problem similar to yours. Could you solve it? Or with other software different from Matlab?
Thank you,
Damian.

Comment: @Damian: I have converted your answer to a comment. Because you do not have 50 reputation points yet, [you can only comment on your own questions and answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work/19757#19757). So, you didn't do anything wrong; the "add comment" button will only appear for you once you gain 50 points. Here is an [explanation of reputation points](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work/7238#7238).

Answer (score 1):

This is called a *singular* boundary-value problem. Matlab can handle some singular BVPs (look at the documentation for `bvp4c` and the `SingularTerm` option in bvpset) so you need to bring your equation in the form that Matlab can handle.

**Added later:** I've never used this option before, but here is how I would start. When bringing the equation to first-order form, one normally introduces a vector $(F_1,F_2)$ with $F_1(K) = F(K)$ and $F_2(K) = F'(K)$ so that the equation becomes
$$
\begin{align}
F_1' &= F_2, \\
F_2' &= \frac{3.45}{0.02K^2} F_2 + \frac{0.08}{0.02K^2} F_1 + \frac{3.45}{0.02K^2}.
\end{align}
$$
As you noticed, Matlab requires the equation to be of the form $y' = \frac1x Sy + f(x,y)$  ...

**Added yet later:** I initially thought that one could get rid of the $1/K^2$ terms by using $F_1(K) = F(K)$ and $F_2(K) = KF'(K)$ but as Qiang Li noted (in more polite terms) I made a stupid mistake. In fact, in the original equation the boundary point $K=0$ is an irregular singular point, while in the equations that Matlab can handle the boundary point is a regular singular point. My uneducated guess would be that the algorithm implemented in Matlab won't be able to handle your equation. Sorry.

Comment: looks like Matlab fixes the SingularTerm to be S*y/x, where S is a constant. But I have essentially S*y/x^2. How am I going to deal with this situation?

Comment: you meant $F_2(K) = KF'(K)$? This will not work! seems that you made a mistake somewhere...

Comment: Yes, I meant $F_2(K) = KF'(K)$ and I made a mistake. Sorry about that. I edited my answer to correct this.

Comment: the problem is that: the first terms is still $$\frac{3.45}{0.02K^2} F_2$$ instead of $$\frac{3.45}{0.02K} F_2$$.

Comment: Oops, you're right, I'm stupid ... Thanks for your correction. In that case, I don't know how to do this :(